# Addind a definiton when pressing F12 in VSCode React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm studying React, and I have discovered a interesting tought.
I have an Lifted State in my app, and i have a handle function to a child component.
When you press F12 on the destructured object that contains the handle, VSCode doesn't know where to point you. Can this type of pointer helper be added by hand?

```
export default function App() {
  
  const [items,setItems] = useState([]);
  function handleAddItems(item){
    setItems((items) => [...items,item]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Logo />
      <Form onAddItems={handleAddItems}/>
      <PackingList items={items}/>
      <Stats />
    </div>
  );
}

function Form(**{onAddItems}** /* function */) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("5");
..... etc ....
}
```

When having **onAddItems** highlighted and pressing F12, I would like VSCode to point me either at the Usage of the Form component or at the function handleAddItems